# Uncrustify - only report errors without changing the file

Tags: c++, uncrustify

Is it possible to only list the set of rules which would have failed on input file without actually applying them? I find it too harsh to just modify the file without letting developer know that file is getting changed under the hood but I would like to get common coding standards and cause build breaks when rules are broken.

I know about `--check` flag but it only returns whether it succeeded or not without letting developer know which rule failed on which line. Perfectly I would like to get something like:

```
test.cpp - uncrustify failed on line 42, incorrect use of tabs - pos 0:6.
```

Also if you know other options where this could be more easily achieved please let me know.

Comment: copy the file, get the errors, copy the original file back. What happens if you change the file to read only before running.

Comment: Well that is the question - where can I get the errors? I didn't find log anywhere.

Comment: Also one option is to save output and run diff between original and the uncrusified file which would show me what has changed. But I would like to get more verbose output with information what rules did get broken.